# Branch specific file versions of untracked files

Tags: git, sensitive-data

A simple example.  Database configuration is stored in config.php file.

This file contains sensitive data (database credentials) so it is added to .gitignore.  We don't want it in our public repository.

The master branch works with our production site.  The develop branch works with our testing site.  Both sites have different database credentials.

If config.php was tracked, we could use branch specific versions of config.php simply by adding this line to our .gitattributes file.

```
config.php merge=ours
```

How can we keep a file out of our public repo (.gitignore) AND keep branch specific versions of it locally (.gitattributes)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keep a different configuration file (untracked) for each branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25571031/keep-a-different-configuration-file-untracked-for-each-branch)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you an easier method:

You could create other file with name, say, `test_config.php` with test database credentials. This file should be untracked too. So in production branch you should use `config.php` and in test branch `test_config.php`.

It is very simple and robust solution compared to complicated git workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

there are several thigs you can look at:

https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files#ignoring-versioned-files

```
Read the part: Ignoring versioned files
```

http://www.twinbit.it/en/blog/storing-sensitive-data-git-repository-using-git-crypt