# How to manage local files in git, prevent merge to master

Tags: git, git-merge, gitignore, atlassian-sourcetree

Let's say i have a dev branch for local development.
On this branch there are files with local specific settings, eg composer.json, .lock, etc/config.php.

What would be the best way to manage these files.
I want to commit them to my dev branch, but that would merge them in master at a later point.

I don't want to stash these files all the time, thats just inconvenient.
I dont want to cherry pick all the commits each time merging to master.
Should i add these to gitignore? What if i change composer.json at a later point with an update that actually needs to get merged to my master.

Any tips or flows would be appreciated. I'm using sourcetree.

Comment: Not precisely a duplicate, but see https://stackoverflow.com/q/25571031/1256452